# Error when updating a WKInterfaceTable while an alert is shown

Tags: alert, watchos, wkinterfacetable

My watch extension displays a `WKInterfaceTable` when new data is available. This can happen any time.
Depending on the situation, an alert can also be shown any time.

**The problem:**

When the `WKInterfaceTable` is updated while the alert is shown, I get the following log:

> Watch Extension[58209:13081232] [TableView] Warning once only:
>   UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents
>   without being in the view hierarchy (the table view or one of its
>   superviews has not been added to a window). This may cause bugs by
>   forcing views inside the table view to load and perform layout without
>   accurate information (e.g. table view bounds, trait collection, layout
>   margins, safe area insets, etc), and will also cause unnecessary
>   performance overhead due to extra layout passes. Make a symbolic
>   breakpoint at UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy to catch
>   this in the debugger and see what caused this to occur, so you can
>   avoid this action altogether if possible, or defer it until the table
>   view has been added to a window.

I did set this breakpoint and the app stopped at the critical point, but I don’t know how to proceed:
Since both events are asynchronous, I had to check before any `WKInterfaceTable` update if an alert is shown, and to defer the update until the alert has been dismissed. I cannot believe that this is what one should do.

What is the right solution?

**EDIT:**

Sorry, by now I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57897288/1987726) and it seems as if this is a warning that can simply be ignored...

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue while displaying an alert.  Funny that it's coming from UITableView, while using a WKInterfaceTable.  I also assume it can be ignored, but open to anyone else's solutions that actually removed the warning.