# UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy error: Warning once only (iOS 13 GM) in Xamarin.Forms iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am facing an issue that the UI of my screen is not loading because of the following error

```
[TableView] Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a window). This may cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to load and perform layout without accurate information (e.g. table view bounds, trait collection, layout margins, safe area insets, etc), and will also cause unnecessary performance overhead due to extra layout passes. Make a symbolic breakpoint at UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy to catch this in the debugger and see what caused this to occur, so you can avoid this action altogether if possible, or defer it until the table view has been added to a window. Table view: <UITableView: 0x7fdcc8488800; frame = (0 24; 1024 1342); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600003c013b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000039f8fc0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {1024, 72}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; dataSource: <Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_ListViewRenderer_ListViewDataSource: 0x600003070790>>
```

Can any one please help me regarding this to resolve this issue. This issue I am getting is only in the 13.3 version of the ipad and it there are no problems in the iPhone 13.3 version.

Please help me in resolving this.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue just ran into this issue only when starting the app while the device was landscape on **iPadOS 13** ?

if yes,maybe you could refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57897288/uitableviewalertforlayoutoutsideviewhierarchy-error-warning-once-only-ios-13-g),even though it's native ios project.

Comment: I am getting this issue even in potrat mode as well. I am just trying to downgrading the xocde from 11.3v to 11.0 to find whether it is xcode problem or not

Comment: 11.0 is not compatiable to the latest OS version. Can you please suggest simething to resolve it

Comment: @PraveenBaruri is the method in the link above could work ?

Comment: It is in native iOS. But I need to get the solution in xamarin.forms

Comment: i will try it and tell you later